# jQuery draggable in Firefox 11 returns XrayWrapper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-draggable

So I have a simple table that I made the rows draggable on.  The thing I want to do is change something about the event.target in the start and stop functions.  This works easily in Chrome because event.target returns the table row.  However, in Firefox 11 (11?  That was fast) it returns:

> [11:58:22.135] [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLTableRowElement]]

So if I wanted to change the css background, for example, how would I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        axis: 'y',
        revert: true,
        start: function(event, ui){
            console.log(event.target);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            console.log(XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(event.target.style));
        }
    });
});

</script>

<html>

<table>
<tr class="drag">
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Console prints:

> [11:58:22.135] [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLTableRowElement]]
>
> [11:58:23.753] [object XrayWrapper [object CSSStyleDeclaration]]

Note that unwrap doesn't seem to do anything (one of the several fixes I found on the Google).  So how do I either unwrap this object or not have it wrapped in the first place so that I can mess up the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of XrayWrapper is to give you an unadulterated view of the DOM node.  So in particular, getting .style on it should work exactly as you would expect it to: it returns an XrayWrapper around the CSSStyleDeclaration, and setting its .background should change the background.

Comment: So it does!  `event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';` worked.  Not sure why I couldn't figure that out...